# Role mapping in kibana configuration for wso2

Tags: wso2, kibana, elk

I am trying to configure elk for the wso2. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/ I followed this for configuring the elk components. In the `create role mapping` section it was told to use the following steps,

1. Login to Kibana using basic authentication and go to Stack Management under the Management section in the left menu. Click Role Mappings under the Security section.
2. In the Create Role Mapping section, add a new role mapping by providing a Mapping name.
3. Select a role that has access to the particular dashboard from the Roles.
   But this `role mapping`  feature is only available for elk subscribed users. Is there any work around to this?

Is this step necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only required if you need SSO with WSO2 for Kibana. So if you can log into those systems separately you don't need to configure this.